# How to create kafka topic partition using camel

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

- I am using **camel-kafka**, **camel-spring-boot-starter** in spring-boot project to route a message from one kafka topic to another.
- On some topics, my current application, which is only using **camel-kafka** and **camel-spring-boot-starter**, (and no spring-cloud-stream) is the producer.
- Is there a way to increase the partition count using camel kafka?

---

In camel we provide using urls.. something like ... `uri(kafka:localhost:9092...`.

*Is there any configuration in camel-kafka using which we can increase the kafka topic partition count?*

Answer (score 0):

No. Partitions count shouldn't be increased outside from kafka. You can only assign a number of partitions on topic creation step. And then you can manually increase them using admin tools for kafka.

Answer (score 0):

camel-kafka component wan't help you with increasing partition count. But you can try to use this solution:

[Kafka : Alter number of partitions for a specific topic using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437301/kafka-alter-number-of-partitions-for-a-specific-topic-using-java/37480937#37480937)

and create camel bean or camel processor basing on this.